# Solving $Ax=b$ for different values of $a$, $c$

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

The solution to part a is $x_1=\frac{cd-bf}{ad-bc}$ and $x_2=\frac{af-c^2}{ad-bc}$.

For part b we then get $x_1=\frac{f}{c}-\frac{d}{b}$ and $x_2=\frac{c}{b}$ so the calculation is still valid.

I’m having trouble with part c because if $a=c=0$ then $x_1$ and $x_2$ doesn’t exist.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Made a big mistake I thought the top part of $b$ was $c$ when it is in fact $e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the formula derived previously. But observe that 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & b \\
0 &  d
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_2 b \\ x_2 d \end{pmatrix}
$$
So if there exists $x_2$ such that 
$$
x_2 b = e \\
x_2 d = f
$$
then our system can be solved. This can be rewritten in many forms, including
$$\frac{b}{e} = \frac{d}{f}
$$
and states that the vector $(b, d)$ is simply a multiple of $(e, f)$. If you imagine them as vectors originating from zero in 2 dimensions, they have to lie on the same line.